# checking the right condition in AlertDialog in android

Tags: java, android

i want to display in my dialog box if the answer is correct or wrong.. but when i run my application even though the answer is correct the dialog box will always display the wrong condition. hope you can help me. here's my code

```
                AlertDialog.Builder bb= new AlertDialog.Builder(Circles.this);
            Boolean b=(holdV==result);
            if(b){
                bb.setMessage("Correct");
                bb.setPositiveButton("Again",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Circles.this.finish();

                        }
                        });
                }
            else{
                bb.setMessage("Wrong");
                bb.setPositiveButton("Try again!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Circles.this.finish();

                }
                });
                AlertDialog alert=bb.create();
                alert.show();
            }
```

Comment: what are holdv and result? what kind of values they contain?

Comment: result is integer who holds the product if you multiply the two numbers that the user will input in my application while holdV holds the product that i generated. so if result==holdV it will show correct else wrong.

Comment: as Tushar Gupta said is it [Integer] or [int] ?

Comment: the else part only contains `alert.show();` How are you showing the alert when the if statement is true?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to start by checking whether the value of `b` is actually what you think it is. Try adding something like this before your `if` statement:

```
Log.w("test b", "Value of b: " + b);
```

Then run the program and check the output in your logcat.